# Margin persists in replaced fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, margin

What I'm doing in my activity(main activity) is replacing a layout(linear layout id/main_layout) with a fragment. The main_layout has additional child layouts to which I applied some margin. After I applied the margin and I replace the main_layout with a new fragment the margin applied pushes my whole fragment view down. If I remove the margin the fragment is placed how I intended.

**Question**: Why is the margin that is applied to some children elements in the main layout persisted to the new fragment that I replaced? Better ways to do this?

removing the 3 android:layout_margin="10dp" fixes my fragment but I lose the pretty main activity

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ExpandableListView
    android:id="@+id/navdrawer"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/navdrawer_width"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"></ExpandableListView>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">



        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:elevation="5dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:id="@+id/product1_linear_layout"
            android:baselineAligned="false">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/product1_imageView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:src="@drawable/panda"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1">

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>



        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:elevation="5dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:id="@+id/product2_linear_layout"
            android:baselineAligned="false">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:src="@drawable/panda"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1">

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>



        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:elevation="5dp"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:id="@+id/product3_linear_layout"
            android:baselineAligned="false">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:src="@drawable/panda"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1">

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

How I replace the layout with the fragment

```
mCurrentFragment = new UserStoryFragment();
                FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
                fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_layout, mCurrentFragment, mCurrentFragment.getClass().getName()).addToBackStack(mCurrentFragment.getClass().getName()).commit();
```

Below the main activity with main_layout highlighted

[image: main activity]

Replaced fragment with marked undesirable margin

[image: Replaced fragment with marked undesirable margin]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I tried to replace the linear layout that is main_layout's parent, which didn't replace the fragment at all. After changing this parent linear layout to a frame layout everything seems to work.

This fixes my issue

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ExpandableListView
    android:id="@+id/navdrawer"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/navdrawer_width"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"></ExpandableListView>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_layout_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">



        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:elevation="5dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:id="@+id/product1_linear_layout"
            android:baselineAligned="false">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/product1_imageView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:src="@drawable/panda"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1">

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>



        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:elevation="5dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:id="@+id/product2_linear_layout"
            android:baselineAligned="false">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:src="@drawable/panda"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1">

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>



        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:elevation="5dp"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:id="@+id/product3_linear_layout"
            android:baselineAligned="false">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:src="@drawable/panda"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1">

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

```
                    fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_layout_parent, mCurrentFragment, mCurrentFragment.getClass().getName()).addToBackStack(mCurrentFragment.getClass().getName()).commit();
```